# How to merge SharePoint List items into Word 2003 document

Tags: sharepoint, ms-word

I want to build a feature like "Print List" on WSS 3.0, and I planned to convert List data into Word document then print it. Is there any way to merge List items into Word 2003 document, I Googled some solutions but they only work with Word 2007.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to write a custom solution that loops through the list items and generates [WordML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa212812%28office.11%29.aspx). This is the XML format for Word 2003. Here is [a guide](http://wcornwill.wordpress.com/2007/01/17/document-generation-using-wordml-word-2003/) that can get you started.

Once the XML file has been generated you can offer it for download using standard ASP.NET methods. Here is [an example](http://www.devarticles.com/c/a/ASP.NET/HTTP-File-Download-Without-User-Interaction-Using-.NET/1/) that should work. Alternatively you could store the result in a document library and point users to download it from there.

Comment: Glad to help! If this answer solved your problem please click the big Tick icon to mark it as answered. Or if it just helped click the Upvote icon.

Answer (score 0):

How important requirement is to have "*.doc" file? If you just need to able to open document with Word 2003 you can just install [Microsoft Office Compatibility Pack](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3)